# Is there a CSR register indicating the current privilge mode ? (except for sstatus.SPP, mstatus.MPP)

Tags: rust, operating-system, riscv, xv6

I am working on a tiny RISCV based OS. With the reference of xv6, rCore, I learned that when my OS first runs on qemu, the initial privilege mode is m-mode. However, I noticed that in the start code of xv6, we manually set the `mstatus.MPP` to S-mode, then we use `mret` to return to S-mode.

```rust
// set previous mode m-mode
mstatus::set_mpp(mstatus::MPP::Supervisor);
// jump address to kernel_main
mepc::write(kernel_main as usize);
// disable page
satp::write(0);
```

I know when handling a trap (in any mode), we figure out the previous mode by SPP (Supervisor Previous Privilege) or MPP (Machine Previous Privilege). That means, we can only get the **previous privilege mode**, but have no ideal with the current mode.

Maybe we can infer the current running mode by `SPP` or `MPP`, but when I tried to print `MPP` and `SPP` after I entered the S-mode, I found that

```rust
info!("{:?}", sstatus::read().spp());
info!("{:?}", mstatus::read().mpp());
// the output
// User
// User
```

I don't figure out why...

To make sure that S-mode can't visit M-mode's CSR regsiters, there must be some status register to indicate the current privilege mode in order to control the behaviours. Where should interrupt be handled are controlled by `sie`, `mie` registers (section), so interrupt can jump to the right place. But when we `ecall` , we also need to know the current mode to trap into the correct `mtvec` or `stvec`...

Maybe there is some convention that we can infer the current running mode totally by `MPP` and `SPP`, but I have no idea about that (I am confused...)

------------------------------update---------------------------------

In gdb, there is a virtual register named `$priv` indicating the current privilege mode.

https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/RISC_002dV-Features.html

This is not implemented by hardware either....

Comment: Is there a CSR register indicating the current privilege mode ? (except for sstatus.SPP, mstatus.MPP)? Yes, `mstatus.MPRV`. It may or maynot be available for all RISC-v implementations.